# weak operator topology convergence and the trace of spectral projections

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, adjoint-operators, von-neumann-algebras

Let $B(H)$ be the algebra of all bounded self-adjoint linear operators on $H$. Let $\{T_i\}$ be a uniformly bounded net in $B(H)$ converging to $T$ in the weak operator topology. Let $Tr$ be the regular trace on $B(H)$. Is it true that 
$$sup_i Tr (e^{T_i}(\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\infty)) \ge Tr (e^{T}(\varepsilon,\infty)) $$
for any $\varepsilon>0$?
Here $e^{T}(\varepsilon,\infty)$ denotes the spectral projection.

Comment: In the form stated this is certainly not true. If $\epsilon<0$, one can take an operator $T$ with spectrum in $(\epsilon,\epsilon/2)$ and the constant net $T_i=T$ will violate the inequality. I guess it could work for $\epsilon\geq 0$.

Comment: For $\epsilon\geq 0$ the inequality is true if $T_i\to T$ strongly, and in this case one can replace $\epsilon/2$ by $\epsilon$ on the left side and the supremum by liminf. I am not sure about weak convergence yet.

Comment: @MaoWao could u show me the proof of the case of sot？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested in the comments, here is a proof in the case of *strong* instead of weak convergence (and for $\epsilon\geq 0$).

First note that the characteristic function of $(\epsilon,\infty)$ is lower semicontinuous, that is, there exists a sequence of positive continuous functions $f_k$ with compact support such that $f_k\nearrow 1_{(\epsilon,\infty)}$ pointwise. Since the functional calculus is continuous for such functions (Takesaki, Lemma II.4.3), it follows that $f_k(T_i)\to f_k(T)$ strongly for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. As $\mathrm{Tr}$ is weakly lower semicontinuous on bounded sets, this convergence implies
$$
\mathrm{Tr}(f_k(T))\leq \liminf_{i}\mathrm{Tr}(f_k(T_i))\leq \liminf_i \mathrm{Tr}(1_{(\epsilon,\infty)}(T_i)).
$$
Finally, $f_k\nearrow 1_{(\epsilon,\infty)}$ implies $1_{(\epsilon,\infty)}(T)=\sup_k f_k(T)$. Thus we can use the normality of $\mathrm{Tr}$ to see that
$$
\mathrm{Tr}(1_{(\epsilon,\infty)}(T))=\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mathrm{Tr}(f_k(T))\leq \liminf_i \mathrm{Tr}(1_{(\epsilon,\infty)}(T_i)).
$$
Of course, if $\epsilon\geq 0$, we have $1_{(\epsilon,\infty)}\leq 1_{(\epsilon/2,\infty)}$, so this inequality implies the one in the original question.

This argument relies on the continuity of the functional calculus with respect to the strong operator topology. This continuity fails for the weak operator topology and I don't know how to proceed in this case (or if the inequality is even true).

Comment: It is really helpful! Many thx. Do you know any reference for this?

Comment: You proof is very very rigorous and I like it very much. THX so much for your time.

Comment: @user92646, reference for what? Two classic books on operator algebras are Takesaki, Theory of Operator Algebras I - III, and Blackadar, Operator Algebras - Theory of C*-Algebras and von Neumann Algebras.

Comment: THX again!!! I thought there would be a reference for this statement (rather than prove it by ourselves). But anyway, this proof is very nice.